# Call x64 Powershell SQL snap-in from x86 Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script that reads some Access DBs and writes some values into a SQL Server DB.

Since I have Office 32 bits installed, I can only install the 32 bit Access provider.
But I want to use the [SQL Server snap-ins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2011/03/31/loading-sql-server-snapins-into-your-powershell-session.aspx) to run the SQL commands, which are 64 bits.

Now, how can I combine both ? I need to run an Access query using Powershell x86, and send the fetched data to Powershell x64 so that it can insert it to SQL Server.

The only solution I see is dropping the SQL snap-ins, and re-writing the SQL wrappers myself, but that's just sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the SQL Server snap-ins are outdated, and have been replaced with the SQLPS module.

The latest SQLPS version can be downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580 (select the `PowerShellTools.msi` you need).

After installing `x86\PowerShellTools.msi`, the SQLPS module is available from x86 PowerShell, and has the same features as the "old" add-in (`Invoke-SqlCmd`...)